# re-applying jquery to cloned objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is the proper way to re-apply jquery to objects which are cloned??

I have an example I rigged up in jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/49o6arLu/16/

```
<div class="hidden element-holder">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="button">Button</div>
        <div class="green-square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <div class="button">Button</div>
    <div class="green-square"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="add-element">Add Element</div>
```

```
$('div.button').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).parent().children('.green-square').is(':visible')) {
         $(this).parent().children('.green-square').hide();
    }else{
         $(this).parent().children('.green-square').show();
    }
});

$('div.add-element').click(function(event) {
    $('div.element-holder').children('div').clone().insertAfter($('div.element-holder'));
});
```

As you can see, the initial displayed box and button work just fine. However, When you add another element the new element button does not work anymore.

I understand why I have this problem, however I don't know the proper way I should go about re-applying the Jquery to the new elements which are cloned.

Can someone provide a solution to the jquery and provide some explanation as to what you did?

Thanks!

Comment: delegate the events to a container so that you don't have to rebind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the need to re-apply the handler to all the appended elements by having a single delegated click handler on a common parent element.

First of all amend your HTML to include the container, in this case `#element-container`:

```
<div class="hidden element-holder">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="button">Button</div>
        <div class="green-square"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="element-container">
    <div class="element">
        <div class="button">Button</div>
        <div class="green-square"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="add-element">Add Element</div>
```

Then you can amend the `Add Element` button to append to that container:

```
$('div.add-element').click(function (event) {
    $('div.element-holder').children('div').clone().appendTo('#element-container');
});
```

Finally you can add the delegated event handler to the new `#element-container`. Note that I also shortened the logic using `toggle()` and `siblings()`:

```
$('#element-container').on('click', 'div.button', function (event) {
    $(this).siblings('.green-square').toggle()
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/49o6arLu/18/)

Comment: Thanks!!! This is exactly what I was looking for! I figured that I needed to use `.on()` but was very confused as to how to use it in this instance. And knowing I can use `.siblings()` is great!

Answer (score 1):

In order to copy event handlers you should send true in the clone method:

```
$('div.add-element').click(function(event) {
$('div.element-holder').children('div').clone(true).insertAfter($('div.element-holder'));});
```